# Check where a field is used programmably in Apex

Tags: apex, metadata

In Salesforce, it provides the information on where a field is bening used on the screen in oject managger as shown in the following link.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_references.htm&type=5
However, is there a way to get these information via Apex code.
I have figured out how to get the pagelayouts a field is used, however, how about other informaiton like formulas, apex code a field is being used?

Comment: Any way of finding a field is not accurate, until done manually by fetching all components and doing a search via search all functionality of any IDE. There might be fields used within `string` which wont get detected.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dependency API available with which you can mimic similar behavior of screen (*Where is this used*)

However, as @Nagendra Singh mentioned in the comment it is not accurate always. You can use it for guidance purposes or to prepare dependency graph etc.

Link to API(It's in Beta) -
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacomponentdependency.htm

One of the blogs explaining its use of it -
https://forcepanda.wordpress.com/2019/11/13/dependency-api-find-all-the-referenced-metadata/